# Adding Punctuation Marks in SQL

Tags: sql, database

I need to add information into my tables but there are punctuation marks.  How do I add these without closing the statement? I am using **SQL SERVER 2012**

Example:

```
INSERT INTO Song (song_id, album_id, song_name, song_length_minutes, song_length_seconds)
VALUES ( 500, 200, **'Doin' it Right'**, 3, 42)
```

The apostrophe after "Doin" if you enter that it closes out the song_name.  So how do you add this without closing the statement?

Also, What is the best way to do time?  In this example both are seperated so I figured it would just be a numeric value data type?  Is that correct?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE Song (
song_length_minutes DECIMAL (5) NOT NULL,
song_length_seconds DECIMAL (5) NOT NULL );
```

Is that okay to do ? And then in the INSERT statements do as shown above?  Would you only use the UI Logic if your pulling that information?

Comment: Consider using stored procedures and parameterized queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following link should help you: -

http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_escape_special_characters_when_writing_sql_queries

I recommend reading this as it includes information on double escape sequences too.

As seen on the page: -

```
SELECT 'Frank''s Oracle site' AS text FROM DUAL;
```

You could store time as simply seconds and then use your UI logic to convert this to the value that you would like to display.

Answer (score 1):

```
VALUES ( 500, 200, 'Doin'' it Right', 3, 42)
```

You need to escape the quote by doubling the single quote.

Using Sql parameters will do this for you

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if that's what you meant, are you talking about escaping special characters?

```
INSERT INTO Song (song_id, album_id, song_name, song_length_minutes, song_length_seconds)
VALUES ( 500, 200, **'Doin'' it Right'**, 3, 42);
```

What language are you using to run the statement?

You should probably store time in a [time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) field, it will be much easier to move back and forth from DB to code.